# PHP PDO - Imploading array into mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to use an array in my mysql query, when I use my variable holding the array it returns no results, as well as no errors.

```
$location = array("Cornwall", "Devon", "Dorset", "Norfolk & Suffolk", "Somerset", "Wiltshire");

//Query
$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE location IN (:location) AND status = 2 ORDER BY ref LIMIT :limit OFFSET :start");
$sql->bindValue(':location', implode(",", $location), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindValue(':limit', (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':start', (int) $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
$adverts=$sql->fetchAll();
```

This returns no errors no results but the query does work if I hard code the values in such as:

```
$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE location IN ('Cornwall', 'Devon') ");
```

Comment: You will have to bind the locations separately

Comment: It requires some machinery to build up the string sent to `prepare()`, but eventually, each value in `$location` needs its own `?` placeholder.  The linked answer has good solutions using `array_fill()`.

Comment: Note that you cannot _combine_ positional placeholders `?` with named ones like `:start, :limit`, so you will need to change those to `?` instead.

Comment: [This one in particular](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10722827/541091) is concise and should work for you - you'll just need to add the other 2 params for start & limit onto the array sent to `execute()`.

Comment: Do you have any example of using "?" in the query i cant get it to work with the :start & :offset values in the query